# How are command-line GUIs made?

Tags: linux, shell, user-interface, command-line, tui

I've always wanted to know how CL GUIs like `top` or `nano` or `vi` are constructed? I have a need to actually make one and am looking for a guide or tutorial on the general idea behind them.

Comment: I am interested in the answers for this question myself but I know `ncurses` which is a handy library to create GUI elements like windows, textboxes, buttons etc. I think it isn't suited for something like `vi` but it allows GUI creation in the shell.

Comment: @halo: curses basically came from `vi`.

Comment: @tripleee: "The name "curses" is a pun on cursor optimization.[6] Sometimes it is incorrectly stated that curses was used by the vi editor. In fact the code in curses that optimizes moving the cursor from one place on the screen to another was borrowed from vi, which predated curses.[4]" (Wikipedia)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a [bunch of them.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface)

Also there is a [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface#Examples_of_programming_libraries).

- [CDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDK_%28programming_library%29)
- [Dialog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialog_%28software%29)
- [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)
- [Newt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newt_%28programming_library%29), a widget-based toolkit
- [PDCurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDCurses)
- [SMG$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMG%24)
- [Turbo Vision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Vision)

Comment: Recent *PDCurses* versions (3.4), unless you're compiling them for DOS, will require *X Window System* and, particularly, any of *Athena Widget Set* implementations (`libXaw`, `libXaw3d` or `libneXtaw`); one will be unable to run an application linked against `libXCurses.so` and/or `libXpanel.so` from a Linux/*BSD/Solaris console.

So *PDCurses* can hardly be named a TUI toolkit nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

You could start by reading about [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/), it’s a very well-known library to draw on the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Check out [TWIN](https://github.com/cosmos72/twin) (apparently, inspired by *Turbo Vision*) by Massimiliano Ghilardi. More screenshots are available [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/twin/). Be sure to use the *GitHub* version, as *SourceForge* repository has been unmaintained since 2002.

[image: TWIN running on Linux console]

If you don't mind your GUI running in a JVM, take a look at [*Lanterna*](https://code.google.com/p/lanterna/) (*Java* and [*Clojure*](https://github.com/sjl/clojure-lanterna/) bindings).

I've also seen a [post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/750873/Turbo-Vision-resurrected-for-Csharp-and-with-XAML) about *Turbo Vision* "ported" to (or rather rewritten using) *C#* and *XAML*, but haven't had a chance to examine it.